# Is it possible to display only a certain div within an iframe?

Tags: css, html

Let's say i have an iframe with the page 2.htm set as the src.

```
<iframe src="2.html"></iframe>
```

So this shows the 2.html. But 2.html has a div with the id 'within'. I want to only display the contents of 'within'.

How would i do this?

Comment: have you edit privileges for 2.html and could add some javascript or is it a foreign website you cannot change anything on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the CSS and html code to accomplish the task:

```
<style>
#outerdiv
{
   width:446px;
   height:246px;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}

#inneriframe
{
   position:absolute;
   top:-412px;
   left:-318px;
   width:1280px;
   height:1200px;
}
</style>
<div id="outerdiv">
    <iframe src="2.html" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/57MRn/

**How does this work**
The iframe is moved up within the outerdiv until only the within div is shown.