# show div from one page into another using iframe

Tags: jquery, html

I have a trying a to show a a div element from one page into another using iframe. IS it possible? I can probably get the entire page but what if want just a specific part of the page?

Comment: Can you fix your question? All the "a"s are confusing me.

Comment: You are not explaining this clearly. "Show" = copy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287933/is-it-possible-to-display-only-a-certain-div-within-an-iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can try using anchors.
On the parent page, add an ID to the `div` if you haven't done so already.
Then, in the `iframe`, set the `src` to 'http://yoursi.te/#div-id' where `div-id` is the ID of the `div.

This makes it so that the `iframe` automatically scrolls down to the `div` instead of starting from the top.

Other than that, you can try dynamically removing elements from the DOM using JavaScript when a URL parameter is set (the `iframe` points to 'http://yoursi.te/?only-div=true').

Then on the parent site, [get the query using JavaSciript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery) and remove all other elements except for the `div` if the parameter returns `'true'`.